# Lecture recorder for linux (presentation + voice + doodling)

Tags: linux

There are many lectures and presentations on youtube where you can see a powerpoint presentation (or pdf, or whatever) through the screen, a voiceoiver of the lecturer giving the presentation, and on occasion, them drawing/circling/pointing at stuff visible, or adding notes (solving equations,...).

Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn7ei2ENJbI (i do not need the camera/webcam feature)

Is there such software (or a combination of programs) available for linux?

Answer (score 0):

[VideoLAN Client (VLC)](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/) is a media player that can [stream the desktop display to file.](https://www.wikihow.com/Screen-Capture-to-File-Using-VLC) VLC is available for various Linux distros, and many, such as Ubuntu, provide customized installation.

BTW, note the default capture rate is only 1 FPS, which you'd certainly increase for capturing a presentaion.